# For loop optimizing in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have read the below code today in Java Tutorials.

```
StackTraceElement elements[] = e.getStackTrace();
for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
}
```

I might write the code like as following as a newbie.

```
StackTraceElement elements[] = e.getStackTrace();

for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
}
```

Or like as following.

```
int n = elements.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
}
```

I just want to ask what's the difference between them? Are there other more excellent approaches to optimize the for loop in Java?

Comment: TBH `for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {` is not nice

Comment: @EricZhang Could you post a link to the tutorial where you saw this?

Comment: @Kayaman Just from Java Tutorial. The url is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The golden rule of optimisation is, DON'T.

The second golden rule is, NOT YET.

The third golden rule is actually a question, HAVE YOU MEASURED?

Answering your question, go with whatever is the accepted standard in your team: your code should not be any different unless it does something *really* different. That is, in a good team the code is all similar and boring. Any step aside is a huge flashing sign saying, "Careful, it's an exception from the rule!" — and unless you want to say exactly that, go with whatever others use.

Now, code-wise, the answer is in the compiler:

```
import java.util.logging.*;

public class ForLoop {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("log");

    public static void a(Throwable e) {
        StackTraceElement elements[] = e.getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
        }
    }

    public static void b(Throwable e) {
        StackTraceElement elements[] = e.getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
        }
    }

    public static void c(Throwable e) {
        StackTraceElement elements[] = e.getStackTrace();
        int n = elements.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
        }
    }
}
```

compiles into

```
alf-pro:Learning alf$ javap -p -c ForLoop.class 
  Compiled from "ForLoop.java"
  public class ForLoop {
    private static java.util.logging.Logger logger;

    public ForLoop();
      Code:
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return        

    public static void a(java.lang.Throwable);
      Code:
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/lang/Throwable.getStackTrace:()[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;
         4: astore_1      
         5: iconst_0      
         6: istore_2      
         7: aload_1       
         8: arraylength   
         9: istore_3      
        10: iload_2       
        11: iload_3       
        12: if_icmpge     36
        15: getstatic     #3                  // Field logger:Ljava/util/logging/Logger;
        18: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/util/logging/Level.WARNING:Ljava/util/logging/Level;
        21: aload_1       
        22: iload_2       
        23: aaload        
        24: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StackTraceElement.getMethodName:()Ljava/lang/String;
        27: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/util/logging/Logger.log:(Ljava/util/logging/Level;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        30: iinc          2, 1
        33: goto          10
        36: return        

    public static void b(java.lang.Throwable);
      Code:
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/lang/Throwable.getStackTrace:()[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;
         4: astore_1      
         5: iconst_0      
         6: istore_2      
         7: iload_2       
         8: aload_1       
         9: arraylength   
        10: if_icmpge     34
        13: getstatic     #3                  // Field logger:Ljava/util/logging/Logger;
        16: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/util/logging/Level.WARNING:Ljava/util/logging/Level;
        19: aload_1       
        20: iload_2       
        21: aaload        
        22: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StackTraceElement.getMethodName:()Ljava/lang/String;
        25: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/util/logging/Logger.log:(Ljava/util/logging/Level;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        28: iinc          2, 1
        31: goto          7
        34: return        

    public static void c(java.lang.Throwable);
      Code:
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/lang/Throwable.getStackTrace:()[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;
         4: astore_1      
         5: aload_1       
         6: arraylength   
         7: istore_2      
         8: iconst_0      
         9: istore_3      
        10: iload_3       
        11: iload_2       
        12: if_icmpge     36
        15: getstatic     #3                  // Field logger:Ljava/util/logging/Logger;
        18: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/util/logging/Level.WARNING:Ljava/util/logging/Level;
        21: aload_1       
        22: iload_3       
        23: aaload        
        24: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StackTraceElement.getMethodName:()Ljava/lang/String;
        27: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/util/logging/Logger.log:(Ljava/util/logging/Level;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        30: iinc          3, 1
        33: goto          10
        36: return        

    static {};
      Code:
         0: ldc           #7                  // String log
         2: invokestatic  #8                  // Method java/util/logging/Logger.getLogger:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/logging/Logger;
         5: putstatic     #3                  // Field logger:Ljava/util/logging/Logger;
         8: return        
  }
```

As you can see, `a()` and `c()` are only different in [variable assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iload_n), and therefore will behave pretty much the same in JVM, JITted or not. `b()` is slightly different: here, `arraylength` is called within the loop. As @thurstycrow notes, it is not necessarily a performance problem, but it may be.

So when it comes to real-life performance, you need to be sure that it is worth considering. A code examining the stack trace *is almost never worth optimising,* as you're not expected to grab a stacktrace over and over again. Moreover, I would argue that logging is way more expensive than array length check.

But if we imagine that you have a case when you need to optimise this particular bit of code, say you're writing a custom monitoring tool that examines all the exceptions thrown and you want it to be awfully slow rather than terminally slow (you see, collecting the stack trace is expensive; navigating it is usually dirt cheap), you need to measure it in the wild, as JIT can and will take into account everything that happens *around* this code as well.

But that's a boring answer, so let's still do some benchmarking even though we know it doesn't make much sense — after all, we can, so why not? A good benchmarking tool that you can use is [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/); you can go and play with it following the tutorial, or just grab this answer.

The benchmark will be,

```
package org.sample;

import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;

@State(Scope.Thread)
public class ForLoop {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("log");
    static {
        logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }

    private StackTraceElement elements[] = new Exception().getStackTrace();

    @Benchmark
    public void a0() {
        for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void a() {
        for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void b() {
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void c() {
        int n = elements.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void d() {
        for (StackTraceElement e: elements) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMethodName());
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void e() {
        Arrays.stream(elements)
            .forEach(item -> logger.log(Level.WARNING, item.getMethodName()));
    }
}
```

(more on `a0` later; answers with for-each and streams included). When we run it,

```
alf-pro:test alf$ java -jar target/benchmarks.jar  -wi 5 -i 5 -t 4 -f 1
# JMH 1.13 (released 41 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0, VM 25.0-b70
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 4 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.ForLoop.a

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:01:00
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 139092694.098 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 130833602.261 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 121355640.666 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 114037414.954 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 110355992.809 ops/s
Iteration   1: 111331613.966 ops/s
Iteration   2: 111401698.736 ops/s
Iteration   3: 108193438.523 ops/s
Iteration   4: 105277721.260 ops/s
Iteration   5: 103549199.780 ops/s


Result "a":
  107950734.453 ±(99.9%) 13602765.938 ops/s [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (103549199.780, 107950734.453, 111401698.736), stdev = 3532595.117
  CI (99.9%): [94347968.515, 121553500.391] (assumes normal distribution)


# JMH 1.13 (released 41 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0, VM 25.0-b70
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 4 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.ForLoop.a0

# Run progress: 16.67% complete, ETA 00:00:51
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 96143259.419 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 107561397.775 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 97488364.065 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 95880266.969 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 96943938.140 ops/s
Iteration   1: 95208831.922 ops/s
Iteration   2: 94012219.834 ops/s
Iteration   3: 95369199.325 ops/s
Iteration   4: 96090174.793 ops/s
Iteration   5: 90375159.036 ops/s


Result "a0":
  94211116.982 ±(99.9%) 8743077.939 ops/s [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (90375159.036, 94211116.982, 96090174.793), stdev = 2270549.576
  CI (99.9%): [85468039.043, 102954194.921] (assumes normal distribution)


# JMH 1.13 (released 41 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0, VM 25.0-b70
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 4 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.ForLoop.b

# Run progress: 33.33% complete, ETA 00:00:41
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 58778298.331 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 66786552.916 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 67834850.418 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 69421299.220 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 72392517.533 ops/s
Iteration   1: 70791625.464 ops/s
Iteration   2: 70393808.080 ops/s
Iteration   3: 68931230.026 ops/s
Iteration   4: 67113234.799 ops/s
Iteration   5: 71628641.383 ops/s


Result "b":
  69771707.950 ±(99.9%) 6847578.759 ops/s [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (67113234.799, 69771707.950, 71628641.383), stdev = 1778294.458
  CI (99.9%): [62924129.192, 76619286.709] (assumes normal distribution)


# JMH 1.13 (released 41 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0, VM 25.0-b70
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 4 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.ForLoop.c

# Run progress: 50.00% complete, ETA 00:00:31
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 87120233.617 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 88506588.802 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 82506886.728 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 75379852.092 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 83735974.951 ops/s
Iteration   1: 80107472.633 ops/s
Iteration   2: 85088925.886 ops/s
Iteration   3: 81051339.754 ops/s
Iteration   4: 85997882.597 ops/s
Iteration   5: 87092494.956 ops/s


Result "c":
  83867623.165 ±(99.9%) 11946241.585 ops/s [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (80107472.633, 83867623.165, 87092494.956), stdev = 3102401.003
  CI (99.9%): [71921381.580, 95813864.750] (assumes normal distribution)


# JMH 1.13 (released 41 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0, VM 25.0-b70
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 4 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.ForLoop.d

# Run progress: 66.67% complete, ETA 00:00:20
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 90916967.864 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 91629586.405 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 107866944.554 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 102023453.435 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 111336773.130 ops/s
Iteration   1: 107770637.269 ops/s
Iteration   2: 107103283.175 ops/s
Iteration   3: 107545862.850 ops/s
Iteration   4: 113804266.277 ops/s
Iteration   5: 114628060.965 ops/s


Result "d":
  110170422.107 ±(99.9%) 14295432.924 ops/s [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (107103283.175, 110170422.107, 114628060.965), stdev = 3712478.533
  CI (99.9%): [95874989.183, 124465855.031] (assumes normal distribution)


# JMH 1.13 (released 41 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0, VM 25.0-b70
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 4 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.ForLoop.e

# Run progress: 83.33% complete, ETA 00:00:10
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 33385239.816 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 38698292.771 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 38876327.513 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 37957299.742 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 39190117.656 ops/s
Iteration   1: 38286235.065 ops/s
Iteration   2: 39449652.416 ops/s
Iteration   3: 38541883.894 ops/s
Iteration   4: 40384962.473 ops/s
Iteration   5: 36975457.540 ops/s


Result "e":
  38727638.278 ±(99.9%) 4934050.936 ops/s [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (36975457.540, 38727638.278, 40384962.473), stdev = 1281357.359
  CI (99.9%): [33793587.342, 43661689.213] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:01:02

Benchmark    Mode  Cnt          Score          Error  Units
ForLoop.a   thrpt    5  107950734.453 ± 13602765.938  ops/s
ForLoop.a0  thrpt    5   94211116.982 ±  8743077.939  ops/s
ForLoop.b   thrpt    5   69771707.950 ±  6847578.759  ops/s
ForLoop.c   thrpt    5   83867623.165 ± 11946241.585  ops/s
ForLoop.d   thrpt    5  110170422.107 ± 14295432.924  ops/s
ForLoop.e   thrpt    5   38727638.278 ±  4934050.936  ops/s
```

we can see that all three methods are so fast that literally the same method results in very different measurement when run a few times. So for this example, I'll just stop here. For your real case, feel free to pick it up with the actual code that creates a problem.

*PS.* Added the for-each and the streaming solutions. As you can see, for-each is pretty much the same (while more readable); streams are noticeably slower. I'm leaving the [`javap` examination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) for those two solutions as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts on explaining on the question. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing, It's exactly the same. Except you save `element.length` in a variable and use that one instead. They do the same, in the same time. the last example is the best as it is the most readably imho.

Comment: additional info: in Java you get no performance gain by assigning the array's length to `n `. In case you also code Javascript: there `element.length` would be recalculated every time, so there the approach with assigning the length to `n ` is recommended. But for Java you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it's better not to store the array length into a variable, because an extra array boundary check would have to be done for each iteration. Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqakUkmsZ1I&index=3&list=LLMo252gCGEz8yAqBmEyatrA&t=1680) (start from 28:00). It describes in detail what effort the JIT compiler makes to optimise the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
for(StackTraceElement element : elements) { 
     logger.log(Level.WARNING, element.getMethodName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it as follows to simply the code.

```
StackTraceElement elements[] = e.getStackTrace();

for(StackTraceElement element : elements) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, element.getMethodName());
}
```

Comment: That should optimize internally to something with `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference to your first version is that the code has to dereference `elements` every single time. Theoretically, storing the value in a variable should thus be more efficient, but this operation is so cheap that in practice you will hardly notice a difference.

The difference to the second version is mostly that you introduce the variable `n` outside the scope of the for-loop. That is, if you want to reuse `n` as a variable name below, you can only do that if it is of the same type (`int` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a slight difference between the two options:

`for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)` : here you will recalculate the elements.length `n` times. Now, most of the time, the size of the collection is cached but there are times in which the size is recalculated on every method call thus increasing the time complexity.

```
final int n = elements.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Here, you calculate the length once and just use it. It is also important to make it final because you don't want anybody to change it.

But, the best method is to use the `for each` loop like this:

`for (StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace())` - this will eliminate the use of a counter, look better and thus more readable and may have some performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

No difference as such .

**case#1**

You are just creating an extra variable and using it.

**case#2**

every time the loop runs `elements.length` method will be computed.

**case#3**

This is as good as case 1.

Comment: `elements.length` is a final value, so it definitely won't be "computed" more than once.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
}
```

for each iteration you access to length variabile of elements .

In other loop :

```
int n = elements.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, elements[i].getMethodName());
}
```

you save length in n variable , but for each iteration you access to n variable .

Is the same .

You can write :

```
StackTraceElement elements[] = e.getStackTrace();
for(StackTraceElement element : elements) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, element.getMethodName());
}
```

A more readable solution to use for ArrayList for example  :

```
arrayName.stream().forEach( item -> System.out.println(item.toString()));
```

This solution requires java 8 .

Comment: The last solution does not seem to work. Did you mean, `Arrays.stream`?

Comment: Last solution is for arrayList object for example.